# PayPal works fine on localhost, but fails while works on aws server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, amazon-web-services, paypal, paypal-sandbox, amazon-ec2

I have integrated paypal to my MVC4 application. PayPal dll version 1.5.0.0, NewtonJson dll version 6.0.0.0
At first i got exception at localhost while getting access token

```
Dictionary<string, string> sdkConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();
sdkConfig.Add("mode", "sandbox");
string accessToken = new PayPal.Api.OAuthTokenCredential("MyClientId", "MySecretId", sdkConfig).GetAccessToken();
```

Exception was

```
Invalid HTTP response: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

From stackoverflow I got a fix

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
```

Its currently working fine on my localhost, but getting exception when uploaded and run on AWS windows instance.

```
Retried 3 times.... Exception in PayPal.HttpConnection.Execute(). Check log for more details.
```

Can somebody help me on this ?

UPDATE

---

I have checked with uploading the same code in mochahost server. Its working perfectly there too
My EC2 instance is Windows Server 2008 DataCenter, 32 bit with IIS7

Answer (score 0):

Make sure TCP443 is open on any elastic load balancer (ELB) you are using and in the security group assigned to the EC2 instance.  In the OS make sure TCP443 is allowed with Windows Advanced Firewall.

Comment: It seems the ports are open. This site is https and if it is so can we assume the port area is perfect ?

Comment: Are you able to confirm communication on TCP443 by other means?  The two areas that come to mind are 1) communication on TCP443 and 2) able to connect to and use a valid SSL certificate.

Comment: we have upgraded from http to https. Is that a proof that we are able to use valid SSL. How we can confirm the two areas ?

Answer (score 0):

It also might mean their API servers are having issues (like they are right now as I'm typing this). Can check their API status page here: https://www.paypal-status.com/api/production